# Let R be a ring and A,B,C ideals such that A+B=R and BC $\subset$ A , then C $\subset$ A

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals

Let R be a ring and A,B,C ideals such that A+B=R and BC $\subset$ A, then C $\subset$ A.

My attempt:

Let x $\in$ C, and as C is an ideal of R, then x=a+b for some b $\in$ B and a $\in$ A. And we can have a'=bx=b(a+b).

I don't know how to prove the problem after that.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: See the linked dupe for the various forms of Euclid's Lemma, including this ideal form.

Answer (score 3):

If R has an identity then you can write 1 as the sum of A and B ... $1=a+b$ for $a\in A, b\in B$. Then multiply by c from the right.

Comment: @Lomp Thanks, that was helpful. Could we do something if R is a ring with no 1?

Comment: Well, at least a condition like $RC=C$ is needed. Then $C=RC=(A+B)C\subseteq AC+BC\subseteq AR+A\subseteq A$.

Comment: @MubarakAlsaeedi no, not in general; for a counterexample, take $R=B=C=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $A=4\mathbb{Z}$